# Inserting autoincrement ID record into Java DB (Derby) using Hibernate session

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, insert, auto-increment

I need to configure hibernate session manager for right inserting records with autoincrement ID. I use Java DB (Derby) and there's probably some problem with application of right dialect (hibernate uses last_insert_id() instead of IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()), but its definition looks ok. Or not? I do not have much experience with that yet, so thanks for a little hint.

Relevant part of servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"/>
    <property name="username" value="app"/>
    <property name="password" value="app"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="net.codejava.spring.model">
    <class name="User" table="USERS">
        <id name="id" column="USER_ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="USERNAME" />
        <property name="password" column="PASSWORD" />
        <property name="email" column="EMAIL" />
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Implementation code:

```
public void InsertUser(User user) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  session.save(user);
}
```

Server log:

```
Info:   Hibernate: insert into USERS (USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL) values (?, ?, ?)
Info:   Hibernate: select last_insert_id()
WARN:   SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 42X01
```

Comment: So, it's maybe a problem of JDK 8 only. When I switched the project down to JDK 7, it works fine.